# Why do newlines turn into spaces or disappear in Opera for contentEditable documents?

Tags: html, newline, opera, contenteditable

Why do newlines appear as spaces or disappear on Enter/Return key in Opera for contentEditable documents?

Try out this demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>contentEditable demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" dir="ltr">
<h1>Welcome to the contentEditable demo!</h1><p><span style="font-size: xx-large">
Try<span style="font-size: small">to type some text before the word "Try". You will see that random spaces are inserted before the word. Press Enter; you will see that the newline on the top disappears.</span></span></p></body>
</html>
```

Opera 11.50 Build 1074 on Windows Vista

Is this an Opera bug? I did not experience this bug with Windows Internet Explorer 8, Safari, Google Chrome, or Firefox 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that I may have discovered why from these links:

[whatwg] Handling of collapsed whitespace in contenteditable:

http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-June/032187.html

> - An nbsp at the end of a line makes the last word longer, so when you hit space, **the last word on the line might jump to the next line. Then
>     when you type a letter, the nbsp gets converted to a regular space and
>     the word jumps back to the previous line.**  (I observed this in Opera. 
>     IE and Gecko seem to have some special-case to avoid this; WebKit
>     avoids it with a more general hack that I'll note later.)
> - An nbsp that winds up immediately before a word **will cause the word to be indented if it happens to start a line**.  Gecko seems to be very
>     careful to avoid this case, but all other engines do it sometimes.
> - A long run of spaces of which some are spaces and some are nbsp's can result in nbsp's at the beginning of a line.  Thus if you type
>     three spaces in between two words for whatever reason, in some cases
>     **the second word can be indented**.  This is probably not what users
>     want.

Bug 13011 - [editing] Encourage authors to use "white-space: pre-wrap" for contenteditable="" and .designMode=true:

https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13011

> Example of a potential problem without pre-wrap: if the user types
>   "foo  bar", with two spaces in between, that will become either
>   "foo  bar" or "foo  bar".  In the first case, "foo "
>   might wrap to the next line even though "foo" alone could fit on the
>   current line.  In the second case, if " bar" starts a line, **it
>   will be visibly indented**.

Best practices for in-page editors:

http://developers.whatwg.org/editing.html#best-practices-for-in-page-editors

> In the former case, "yellow⍽" might wrap to the next line ("⍽" being
>   used here to represent a non-breaking space) even though "yellow"
>   alone might fit at the end of the line; in the latter case, "⍽ball",
>   if wrapped to the start of the line, **would have visible indentation
>   from the non-breaking space**.